# Laravel 4 cookie session lifetime getting changed automatically

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-4

I've created "remember me" functionality in Laravel 4. For this, I've used below code to set custom session. I've set the session in login function and checked within the same function, then its giving correct result that is "One Year". But when I redirected to dashboard with showDashboard() function and checked the session again in within function, then session changing to 120 min that is "Two Days".

**Login Function:**

```
public function actionLogin{
   //User authentication code

    $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
    Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime); 

    //Config::get('session.lifetime'); //<---Giving expected result i.e "One year"
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
}
```

**Dashboard function:**

```
public function showDashboard(){
       Config::get('session.lifetime'); //<--- Giving o/p 120 i.e two hours 
}
```

Comment: Why not use Laravel's own authentication and remembering users? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: @Karl Yes, I could, but I am using Laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

When calling `Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);` you're only setting the config for that one instance, not overwriting the config value (which can be found in config/session.php)

So when you're calling `Config::get('session.lifetime')` it will return the default value, which is 120.

In order to change this I would modify `app/config/session.php`, so that this line:

```
'lifetime' => 120
```

becomes:

```
'lifetime' => 525600
```

This will mean that the default value is 1 year.

Comment: Thanks, @Karl but I want to change it by dynamically for "remember me" functionality...

Comment: In that case you'd want to create a cookie and specify a length of time, not change the config value for sessions.. `Cookie::make('name', 'value', $lifetime)`